# CoreData Batch request error in a Swift program

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm getting a failure trying to perform a batch delete, and I cannot figure what is happening.

I call the request:

```
self.deleteAllRecords(entity: self.someEntity)
```

and the function is:

```
func deleteAllRecords( entity : String)
    {
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
        let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetch)
        
        do {
            let result = try context.execute(request)
            print("result: ", result)
        }
        catch {
             print ("There was an error 1")
        }
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print ("There was an error 2")
            }

    }
```

I'm getting hung up at error 1. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you would print the actual error instead of just reporting that an error occurred. Include `\(error)` in the print statement.

Comment: hmm. I'm using a `core data /cloudkit` control - Seam3. That seems to be resulting in the. fuller error message:   `Error Domain=SMStoreErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seam3 does not currently support the `NSBatchDeleteRequest` operation, so an `invalidOperation` error is thrown.